# Spyder 4.0.0 beta1: How to select dark theme for the entire interface?

Tags: python, spyder

I've just installed `Spyder 4.0.0b`, and according to the [changelog](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Beta-version-changelog) it's now possible to activate a **`dark theme`** for the entire interface. But how? I can't find any options in the vicinity of `Tools > Preferences > Syntax coloring`:

[image]

There doesn't seem to be anything under `View > Window Layouts` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The dark theme for the interface will come in our **4.0beta2** version, that's why it's not available in beta1.